# jquery link selector doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a script where a user clicks on the link type he wants and it opens it up in a small textfield below based on which he clicks.

For example [image: My Example]

But i am having a problem as it pastes the entire code into the text box for some reason?
`<a class="linkInsert" value="1">Link (email &amp; IM)</a>`

http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/

Comment: it should show the numbers not the text is the issue now using some of the edits below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.parent()`

Do this way

`$('#linkText').val($(this).html());`

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/1/

---

to show value of clicked link  (*added a data attribute*)

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#linkText').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/14/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#linkText').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `value` attribute to custom data attribute `data-value` 
 and `data('value')` instead of `html()`. there is no need to use `parent()`

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="1">Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="2">Direct Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="3">HTML Image (websites / blogs)</a></li>
    </br>
    <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="4">HTML Link (websites / blogs)</a></li>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="5">Message Boards</a></li>
</ul>
<input id="linkText" />
```

**JQuery :**

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#linkText').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gQms9/10/)

**NOTE :** There is no value attribute for `a` tag